# Explain please what is a magic file in unix

Tags: man, file-types

We can create magic files with `file -C -m filename`. Also there  is the  `/usr/share/file/magic` folder with a list of magic files on my OS X machine.

But what is this? Would somebody explain, why should we have magic files? How should we create a magic file?

I read the man pages (`man file` and `man magic`), but it is still not clear.

Comment: Look at the `file(1)` man page and it may become clear.

Comment: What parts of the manpages did you not understand?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Unix a file is just a sequence of bytes, however some files have more structure. The `file` command can look at the sequence of bytes and tell you things.for example if the first 4bytes are \177 E L F then it will tell you it is an elf file. It will  then look at more bytes and tell you if it is a core file, an executable or an object file. If the bytes 6 thru 9 are JFIF then it is a picture file and again the program can read more and tell you about it.

A lot of this is driven by data tables rather than being compiled into the program. These data tables are what is in the `magic` files.

So the reason why you have magic files is to allow you to say `file *` and get the program to tell you what you have in the current directory.