# How to ID images that have extra data attached?

Tags: bash, files, file-types

I'm trying to extract images from a complex file. I'm able to break down that file in different sections and extract them all to different files.

The idea then was to use `file` to detect the type of each sections and select only those that are only pictures (JPEG, PNG, BMP, ...). And it works, as long as the sections contain pure, unadulterated image data it detects them as such.

For example:

```
$ file Section_Raw_7BB28B99-61BB-11D5-9A5D-0090273FC14D_body.raw
Section_Raw_7BB28B99-61BB-11D5-9A5D-0090273FC14D_body.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 193 x 58 x 8, image size 11368, 256 important colors, cbSize 12446, bits offset 1078
```

However, when there is some sort of trash data, or metadata I'm still not sure, but X bytes anyway, prepending the file signature for the picture itself file doesn't recognize it as an image (as expected, it is not an image per se).

```
$ file Section_Raw_4B2E0988-9E44-49AE-8B77-F544B1CAF03F_body.raw
Section_Raw_4B2E0988-9E44-49AE-8B77-F544B1CAF03F_body.raw: data
```

It doesn't seem to matter if I tell file not to give up on the first match (`-k`), it won't see the JPEG inside, but after examining the file with an hex editor I noted the typical magic code for JPEGs near the beginning:

[image: JPEG starts near the beginning]

How could I proceed from here? Is there any way to ID files such as this one or should I first get rid of those extra bytes at the beginning for `file` to work?

I still have to assess whether the metadata bytes are always the same length or not, but if they were, is there a way to tell file to start looking at files past them? Or maybe strip the first X bytes of a file producing another one that would be a valid picture?

The alternative seems too daunting to me, looking for magic beginnings and ends of files manually somehow (`grep`ing for hex?) and `dd`ing for the length. Feasible of course, but not as simple or easy to read as someone more seasoned the little Linux utils come up with.

Thanks for your time by the way!

PS. I have uploaded the file here in case you need something to test with: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=71511465902538158650

Comment: You can provide your own `magic file` with different offsets for `file` command if the offsets are fixed. I am guessing from the names that these are "raw" images from an up market camera and they have embedded jpeg images for quick viewing. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393292/194382 has a bit more on magic files, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format explains `raw` a little more.

Comment: you probably looking for `binwalk` or `photorec`